# Problems installing MATLAB engine for python

Tags: linux, matlab, python-2.7

I am using MATLAB R2014b and Python 2.7.7. I installed MATLAB engine for python on my Red Hat linux using the instructions given at: [Install MATLAB Engine for Python](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) After step 4 I get this:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/_arch.txt -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2014b-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2014b-py2.7.egg-info
```

but when I type:

```
import matlab.engine
```

in python command line, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
raise EnvironmentError('The installation of MATLAB Engine for Python is '
EnvironmentError: The installation of MATLAB Engine for Python is corrupted. 
Please reinstall it or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance.
```

I'd appreciate any advice in simple words as I am not a linux professional.

Comment: Did you try to do what it says? "Please reinstall it or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance."

Comment: @A. Donda, I did reinstalled it but it didn't work. No contact yet.

Comment: And apparently there are no error messages during installation? And you use a "supported Python implementation"? Then I've got no idea, sorry. Asking TMW might be your best chance.